# VBA Excel - Set row background depends on cell value

Tags: vba, excel, rgb

I have such rows in Excel:

```
Subject     VariableName    VariableValue
Color       vColor_Chart1   RGB(217,217,217)
Color       vColor_Chart2   RGB(210,110,42)
```

I want to create macro to change row background depens on cell value in VariableValue column.

I have such code for now:

```
Sub SetBackground()

Dim rngRange As Range
Dim rngRow As Range
Dim rgbCell As Range

Set rngRange = Range("A2:K13")
For Each rngRow In rngRange.Rows
    Set rgbCell = Range("E" & rngRow.Row) ' E it is column of VariableValue in my sheet
    rngRow.Interior.Color = rgbCell.Value 'here it doesn't works
Next

End Sub
```

And I don't know how to 'run' RGB function from cell.value.

The error from `rngRow.Interior.Color = rgbCell` row:

> Run-time error '13':
>   Type mismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `rngRow.Interior.Color` to an actual color object, but you're currently setting it to a string. If you change this line in your code:

```
rngRow.Interior.Color = rgbCell.Value 'here it doesn't works
```

To this:

```
If Left(rgbCell.Value, 4) = "RGB(" Then
    rgbValues = Split(Mid(rgbCell.Value, 5, Len(rgbCell.Value) - 5), ",")
    rngRow.Interior.Color = RGB(rgbValues(0), rgbValues(1), rgbValues(2))
End If
```

Then that will build the color object from the numbers in the string.

Comment: This version of solution of my problem is very simple! I thought that I have to do sth like @Jeeped did, but I haven't. :) Thanks!

Comment: You can even do without 'Val', except for the last one:    sp = Split(Mid(c00, 5), ",")
   y = RGB(sp(0), sp(1), Val(sp(2)))

Comment: @snb is correct. I don't need `Val` (even for the third argument – not sure why you thought I still needed it for the last argument). Updated above! By the way, @Jeeped's answer is pretty much exactly the same as mine, though I guess the single `Split` is more concise.

Answer (score 1):

The [RGB Function (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc1dyw8b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a VBA function that builds a color constant from three integers. You cannot use it by passing in a text string that *looks* like a fully formed function call.

If you are absolutely determined to have the formula as text in the cell, a little manipulation to evaluate the formula from its text string should be sufficient.

```
Dim sRGB As String, r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer
sRGB = rgbCell.Value    'example: "RGB(210,110,42)"
r = Int(Split(Split(sRGB, ",")(0), "(")(1))
g = Int(Split(sRGB, ",")(1))
b = Int(Split(Split(sRGB, ",")(2), ")")(0))
'Debug.Print RGB(r, g, b)
rngRow.Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b) 'here it works
```